# Microsoft Azure - Cannot satisfy password requirements when making FTP user credentials

Tags: azure, deployment, ftp, passwords

I cant seem to satisfy password requirements for creating FTP user credentials

I go to
App Service > yourwebapp > Deployment Center > FTP > User Credentials
to make a username and password,
but I can never make a password that satisfies all the requirements.
I have literally dragged my hands across my keyboard pressing every button but I still cant.
Could someone please tell me that I'm not going crazy and that I can follow basic directions.

I used different browsers, both Chrome and Edge, but always get the message
"The specified password does not meet the minimum requirements. The password should be at least eight characters long and must contain capital letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and symbols."

I have verified that both password fields match. Username is in the form of <username>, just like the [docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-configure-credentials)

My sample password is
TestTestTest_1234!@#$
I think it SHOULD meet the requirements.

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK So I found out certain characters are not supported in the password, even if they are not explicitly stated.

Characters not supported include. There may be others but this are the ones I have tested myself.

```
_ (underscore)
#
^
(  )
{  }
[  ]
_ -
+ =
: ;
" '
< >
, .
/
| \
` ~
```